# Is there an efficient alternative for growing dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, bigdata

I am reading a large text corpus in xml format and storing counts of some word occurrences in a dictionary where a key is a tuple of three elements `{('a','b','c'):1}`. This dictionary continuously grows in size while its values get updated.
I need to keep a dictionary in memory all the time ~25GB before writing it to hdf file.

I have tried to find some information about what data types can actually reflect the structure of the current dictionary but did not find any concrete answer. My biggest concern is memory size. Is there any data structure in python that can mitigate these constraints? I have read about [pyjudy](http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyJudy.html) library but looks like it is heavily 32bit and barely developed anymore. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? What aspects of the system are you allowed to change? Is the thing too big to fit in memory? If it is, are you trying to stuff it all into memory somehow anyway?

Comment: you have 25gb of ram? thats alot .... i didnt know you could even have that much even in 64 bit machines .... why do you need to keep it all in memory?

Comment: No idea what you are actually asking.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Some workstations at my company have 32gb, and the theoretical limit for 64 bit is much much higher.  As for this question, I'd suggest that a database would be a better solution than in-memory dict.

Comment: @Joran Beasley if you got a normal 64-bit version of win7 you can access a file up to 1tb. There are some editors which do not open the whole file at once just the needed code. But it is possible to have that much ram being used for a file.

Comment: I am keeping it in memory because I need to update the key values and saving/reopening it multiple times does not sound like a solid optimization idea.

Comment: use a database .... something like redis or some other nosql ... thats what they are made for ... that said if you have enough memory to store the whole dictionary then just do that(if thats what you want at least)

Comment: @minerals I would use some kind of database. i personally prefer sqlite. i read somewhere that it can handle up to 140 terabyte(!)
it is fast, lightweight and simple to use.

Comment: PyJudy provides sparse arrays. Dicts are associative arrays, so if you treat the keys' hashes as array indices, they are already sparse. Thus I don't think PyJudy would have fitted your use-case.

Comment: You shouldn't use traditional ways to process that much data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to keep a dictionary in memory all the time ~25GB before
>   writing it to hdf file.

Does that mean the data is 25GB, or the resulting dictionary is 25GB in memory? That means you'd have **a lot** of those 3-tuples if each element in the tuple is a word. I don't think you actually need all of this in memory. But, I really doubt that the dictionary of three-word tuples to integers is really 25GB.

According to my /usr/share/dict/words, an average word is about 10 characters. Each one is a byte in the most common case. Thirty bytes per record without the integer, and you probably have keys that are 4 bytes. So 34 bytes per record. The dictionary will, of course, add overhead. But still we're talking about more than 600 million 3-tuples, easily. And of course in this case that's distinct word tuples since you're counting each one in the value of the dictionary.

Not totally understand what your question is, I would point you at [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/shelve.html). It gives you something that looks like a dictionary (interface wise) but is disk-backed.

Have you actually tried this? Premature optimization is the root of all evil :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there are other dict implementations, but I'd say you've got 2.5 options:

1. Optimise your encoding locally - that is index your words separately, so that you've got a dictionary of `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, ...}` and then for the triplet dictionary use `{(1,2,3): 1}` instead. This will reduce the memory usage, because strings won't be repeated many times.

2.1. Implement the above in an extension in some other language.

2.2. Just use another language. The whole dictionary and values in python will always have an serious overhead compared to the small values you're storing.

Edit: Longer answer to das-g's comment, because I think it deserves one. Python is good at copying only the data which changes. Immutable values remain in one place when they're assigned to a new variable. This allows the following to work with close to no new allocation:

```
# VmRSS:       27504 kB
In [1]: a=['a'*1024]
# VmRSS:       27540 kB
In [2]: a=['a'*1024]*10000
# VmRSS:       27540 kB
```

But that's not the case for identical values which come from different places. As in - they're created from scratch (for example read from a file) every time, rather than copied from existing value:

```
# VmRSS:       27540 kB
In [4]: a=['a'*1024 for _ in range(10000)]
# VmRSS:       38280 kB
In [5]: b=['a'*1024 for _ in range(10000)]
# VmRSS:       48840 kB
```

That's why if the words are read from some out-of-process source, it's worth deduplicating them yourself, because Python will not do it for you automatically.

So in practice, you could even save memory by doing something that looks silly like substituting:

```
def increase_triple(a, b, c):
    triples[(a,b,c)] += 1
```

with:

```
WORDS = {}
def dedup(s):
    s_dedup = WORDS.get(s)
    if s_dedup is None:
        WORDS[s] = s
        return s
    else:
        return s_dedup

def increase_triple(a, b, c):
    triples[(dedup(a),dedup(b),dedup(c))] += 1
```

As @StefanPochmann mentioned in the comment, the standard function [intren()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern) does pretty much what `dedup()` above does. Just better.

Comment: Python implementations are perfectly able to recognize repeated immutable objects (like strings or tuples) and to only hold them once for all references pointing to them, so your approach Nr. 1 is unlikely to gain any memory efficiency.

Comment: @das-g I edited with the reason for the recommendation and response to your comment

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought python's default implementation (CPython) was de-duplicating immutable objects of independent creation automatically. I was wrong.

Comment: @das-g Not automatically, but with [`intern`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern), for strings you can tell it to: `a=[intern('a'*1024) for _ in range(10000)]` (in Python 3 it's `sys.intern`).

Comment: @StefanPochmann That's awesome, I didn't know it's builtin

Comment: Yours is more general, though, as `intern` is really just for strings. You could shorten it to `def dedup(s): return WORDS.setdefault(s, s)`, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Processing big data with the traditional ways to process small/mid-size data is often a wrong approach, in terms of efficiency and maintainability. Even if you accomplish to do it for today, there is no guarantee that you will be able to do it tomorrow for several reasons(e.g. your data grows larger than your available memory, data partitioning etc.).

Depends on the behaviour of your input, you should have a look at either batch processing engines(Hadoop/Mapreduce, [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/)) or stream processing engines([Apache Storm](https://storm.apache.org/), Spark Streaming).

If you want to continue working with python, Apache Spark has python interface.

Last of all, there is a project called [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/) for interactive big data analytics(My thesis topic). It supports Apache Spark and several other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'd recommend a database, but if you're dead-set on keeping this in Python...

A mapping from words to indexes could help. Replace the key of ('a', 'b', 'c') with (1, 2, 3), where (1, 2, 3) are values in a lookup table.

```
lookup_table = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

This would be of primary use if most of the words you have are really long, and are repeated a lot. If you have (a,b,c), (a,c,b), (b,a,c), (b,c,a), (c,a,b), and (c,b,a), each word is only stored once instead of 6 times.

EDIT: This depends on how you are generating your strings.

```
"ab c" is "ab c" : True
"a"+"b c" is "ab c" : False
```

Another way to do this is to read the file, but when the output grows to a certain point, sort the keys (a-z), and output to a file:

```
aaab:101
acbc:92
add:109
```

then wipe the dictionary and continue with processing. Once the file has finished processing, you can then merge the values. This doesn't use much memory because all the files are sorted; you just need to keep one line per file in memory. (Think mergesort.)

Or you could just use a database, and let it worry about this.